# Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе с ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

При mysql запроса ошибка. 
Привожу часть кода:

```
$select=mysql_query("SELECT id_article, date, caption, text, keywords FROM article ORDER BY date DESK");

 if(!$select){echo mysql_error();} while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){?>...<?}?>
```

Ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'DESK' at line
> 1 Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in Z:homeblogwwwindex.php on
> line 22

Ругается после того, как в запрос вписываю ключевое слово **DESK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно не DESK, а **DESC** будет правильно

Comment: какая глупая ошибка... стыдно)